# Vuetify v-treeview. Change the text

Tags: treeview, vuetify.js, nuxtjs

I use NuxtJs and Vuetify for one project. I need to create a treeview so I would like to do it with v-treeview.
I have a problem with the node name.
Here are my data:

```
items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        data: {
          name: 'Application :',
          id: '1',
        },
        children: [
          {},
        ],
      },
}
```

Here the frontend

```
<v-treeview :items="items"></v-treeview>
```

So I would like to have data.name in text but I can't get it. Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the `item-text` property to your `v-treeview` tag to specify what the value to be displayed is

```
:item-text="data.name"
```

Comment: Can you offer more context for this answer? Any explanation of how it addresses the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `label` slot inside your `v-treeview` like :

```
<v-treeview :items="items">
  <template v-slot:label="{item}">
     <div class="v-treeview-node__label">{{item.data.name}}</div>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```